# How to destroy millions of dependent objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In Rails I have always used `dependent: :destroy` to remove dependent objects.

However in the following scenario it doesn't work properly because Subscriptions and Notifications are very large, with millions of objects that must be destroyed.

```
Users --> Projects  --> Subscriptions
                   \
                    --> Notifications
```

Some problems are:

- the deletion is very slow and can take many hours (I could use a background job)
- I cannot use `dependent: :delete_all` on large tables because it would block the database for a long time
- `user.destroy` wraps all the deletions inside a transaction (I don't think it's good for a database which must serve other queries in the meantime)

What is the Rails way to handle a large destroy with millions of records? Are there any gems that can help and handle the `dependent: :destroy` in a better way (e.g. outside a transaction)? What approach would you suggest in this case?

Comment: I don’t know if there are any gems. I use background jobs and add a status to users and projects (BEING_DELETED) to handle the situation while deletion occurs.

Comment: i would remove the `dependent: :destroy` and trigger a cleanup job through an after_destroy callback. unless there is mission-critical data that needs to be deleted within the same transaction that would do just fine. i don't think that there is a "rails way" to handle such cases.

Comment: @phoet the only problem with your approach is that some errors may occur in the meantime when you try to access to the parent object (e.g. `notification.project` may cause some errors because in your application you expect project to be present)

Comment: that is correct. it's all about tradeoffs, you cant have consistency and speed at the same time (that is what's all the eventual consistency stuff is all about)

Answer (score 3):

Starting from Rails 6.1 it's possible to do `dependent: :destroy_async` to destroy associations in the background

```
 has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy_async
```

just posted this for future reference